# Kotlin wait for coroutine in for loop before going onto next index

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

Hi I am using a for loop to call a coroutine method (that calls retrofit) and for each loop I want the coroutine method to finish (after retrofit responds) but my loop seem to keep going without awaiting for the coroutine method to finish... Below is my looping method:-

```
fun forwardFailedSMS(context: Context) {
            var failed = getFailedSms(context)

            failed.forEachIndexed { index, f ->    
                println("NOW ${index}")
                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    var time = measureTimeMillis {
                        val fn = async {
                            callForwardAPI(context, f)
                        }
                        val result = fn.await()
                    }
                }
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                //I want the above to finish before going to next index...
            }

            refreshSmsList(context!!)
        }
```

Below is the callForwardAPI function that uses Retrofit to call an API:-

```
suspend fun callForwardAPI(context: Context,sms: SmsData) {
        val databaseHandler: DatabaseHandler = DatabaseHandler(context)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://backend.mydomain.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(SMSService::class.java)

        val api = GlobalScope.async {
            val response = retrofit.postForwardSMS(
                sms.sender,
                sms.message
            ).awaitResponse()

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
               println("DONE SUCCESS ${sms.message}")
            }
        }
        api.await()
    }
```

The log "NOW" loops and prints before the "DONE SUCCESS" for that particular loop prints...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move the `.launch{ }` method outside of the `forEach`.
Currently what's happening, is that your suspend methods will be suspended, but inside the launch, so the for can continue.

If you move the launch outside of the for, your for cycle will also suspend at every suspension point

Answer (score 0):

your service call contains coroutine so, you dont need to use coroutine in your **forwardFailedSMS** function. you are creating two independent async job. I assume that using **live data** and **observer** can solve your case.

you need to change your forwardFailedSMS function shown below:

```
lateinit var failedListSize: Int
lateinit var serviceCallResponseCount: Int

fun forwardFailedSMS(context: Context) {
            var failed = getFailedSms(context)
            failedListSize = failed.size
            serviceCallResponseCount = 0

            failed.forEachIndexed { index, f ->    
                println("NOW ${index}")
                callForwardAPI(context, f)
            }

            
        }
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // I assume that you are using viewmodel and fragment. If you use another pattern, you can change onViewCreate to another lifecycle function.
        viewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, Observer{
                println("NOW ${index} observed response")
                serviceCallResponseCount++
                if (serviceCallResponseCount == failedListSize){
                    refreshSmsList(context!!)
                }

        }
}
```

and your callForwardAPI to:

```
val myLiveData: MutableLiveData<QueryOnlinePolicyResponse> = MutableLiveData()
suspend fun callForwardAPI(context: Context,sms: SmsData) {
        val databaseHandler: DatabaseHandler = DatabaseHandler(context)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://backend.mydomain.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(SMSService::class.java)

        val api = GlobalScope.async {
            val response = retrofit.postForwardSMS(
                sms.sender,
                sms.message
            ).awaitResponse()
            // I put postValue here because we are waiting same response count with fail in our observer
            myLiveData.postValue(response)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
               println("DONE SUCCESS ${sms.message}")
            }
        }
        api.await()
    }
```

I believe that this pattern will solve your case. I couldn't try it, I use editor. Pardon me if there are some mistakes.

Answer (score -2):

If you want `forwardFailedSMS()` to remain regular blocking method, you can use `runBlocking` instead of `launch` and `async`

```
...
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    failed.forEachIndexed { index, f ->    
        println("NOW ${index}")
        callForwardAPI(context, f)
    }
}
...
```